# How to check if a string contains only specific characters

Tags: php, string, validation, preg-match, whitelist

I need to check a string to determine if it contains any characters other than `|`, in order to assign those variables that have nothing except `|` a value of NULL (there could be theoretically any number of `|` characters but it likely will not be more than 5-6). Like `||||`

I could see looping through each character of the string or somesuch, but I feel there must be a simpler way.

Comment: Can you give an example of a string you're manipulating?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/[^|]/', $string)) {
    // string contains characters other than |
}
```

or:

```
if (strlen(str_replace('|', '', $string)) > 0) {
    // string contains characters other than |
}
```

Comment: oooh this allows me to continue to not know regex! :p

Comment: The first solution fails on "\n|" because by default regexes don't cross multiple lines

Comment: Proof that @giorgiosironi's comment is incorrect: https://3v4l.org/mCutJ

Comment: Yes the comments is incorrect, https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php states: `The newline character is never treated in any special way in character classes, whatever the setting of the PCRE_DOTALL or PCRE_MULTILINE options is. A class such as [^a] will always match a newline. `

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use regular expressions:

```
if(! preg_match('/[^\|]/', $string)) {
  $string = NULL;
}
```

Comment: This unexplained solution does not need the pipe to be escaped inside of the negated character class.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to check if a string only contains certain characters. To prevent double negation (because I find them harder te read) I decided to use the following regex:

```
preg_match('/^[|]+$/', $string)
```

This checks a string from beginning to end to only contain `|` characters (at least one).

Answer (score 1):

If the string has length after trimming pipes from the front of the string, then it has at least one non-pipe character.

```
if (strlen(ltrim($string, '|')) {
    // has non-pipe characters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`count_chars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) function may be relevant for your usecase:

```php
$str = 'a|b|||e';

$chars = count_chars($str, 1); // [97 => 1, 98 => 1, 101 => 1, 124 => 4]
unset($chars[ord('|')]); // [97 => 1, 98 => 1, 101 => 1]
$chars = array_map(\chr(...), array_keys($chars)); // ['a', 'b', 'e']
```

Comment: This looks exceptionally heavy-handed, no?  Why do so much work?  The asker doesn't need all of the values, just a `true` or `false` outcome.

Answer (score -1):

Fastest and simplest way is possibly the stripos function. It returns the position of a string inside another, or false if it can't be found:

```
if (false === stripos($string, '|')) {
    $string = null;
}
```

The `false ===` is needed for strict type comparison, since stripos could return a zero indicating that the | is on the first char.

You can use a more sophisticated validation engine that makes reading easier. I do recommend [Respect\Validation](http://documentup.com/Respect/Validation). Usage sample:

```
if (v::not(v::contains('|'))->validate($string)) {
    $string = null;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not satisfy the asker's requirements.   The asker needs to know if non-pipes exist.  Determining if a string contains pipes is irrelevant to this task.  Also, there is no reason to use a case-insensitive function when checking for pipes.